# How do I share a group of variables with multiple functions in bash

Tags: bash

I've been getting more familiar with bash scripting lately and its unfamiliar variable scoping.

```
func1() {
    local file="/path/to/a/file.log"

    func2 "$file"
    func5 "$file"
}

func2() {
    local name=$(basename -- "$1")
    local ext="${1##*.}"

    #do stuff
}
```

I have different chains of functions that $file is passed to

func2 -> func3 -> func4

func5 -> func6 -> func7

and so on.

In those functions I may need different parts of the file path, the name, extension or just the path. So far I have just been extracting these parts in each function as needed but this has led to duplicate variables in some functions, which I don't like.

Usually I would use a class to to share a group of variable with a set of functions but bash doesn't have classes. What is the "normal" way to do this in bash?

Should I create all the variables in `func1` and pass them to the functions as needed or should I just use them without passing them unless there is a specific need to pass a variable?

Comment: Can'y you put the path parts in an array and use them as you please inside the functions?

Comment: it would probably help if you could provide (minimal) examples of `func2`, `func3` and `func4` so we can see how you're currently processing `$file`

Comment: @markp-fuso I have added func2 they all do the same thing, just extracting the parts into variables and then using those variables without changing them.

Comment: I believe this question is more fitting in `softwareengineering.stackexchange.com` as it likely would turn opinion-based.

Comment: `What is the "normal" way to do this in bash?` I would argue that normal way to do this is either you start writing spaghetti code or move to something else, like python. `Should I create all the variables in func1 and pass them to the function` There is no "should", it's opinion based. Use which ever is better for your design.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That is an options for the case of the file but it doesn't suit all cases, is there a reason not to create them all in func1?

Comment: @KamilCuk I know how to use Python but that is not what I want to do, I actually want to use bash which I quite like.

Comment: @Gary If you need to split and to work on the string in many functions it's proably easy to make a mistake somewhere. If you do the splitting in one place, it'll be easier to maintain. Split once and then combine the parts of the path you need for each function and provide that as arguments to the different functions.

Comment: @gary *`it (array of values) doesn't suit all cases`* ... so now we need to see some of these *`other cases`* to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: My two cents: Regardless of optimization, I don't pass "preprocessed" values to a function along with the original/raw value (e.g. `$file` and `$ext` together). But I use two types of "global" variables: one that is shared globally in general and likely initialized in main function, and another that is shared by a parent function to its children. I have a general rule to always use all-caps to also identify global variables. Sometimes I would add prefix to it like an underscore to avoid conflict. The "global" variable is declared with `local`.

Comment: I sometimes might name the children function as <parent_func_name>.<child_func_name>. I also might prefix the variables. The strategy will depend on the requirement of the script. I also thought about using lowercase variables instead for the second version of globals I just mentioned with added prefixes perhaps, but I really find that it lacks distinguishability.

Answer (score 3):

You can use global associative arrays to avoid polluting your global namespace

```
#! /bin/bash

setvars() {
    local -r arg="$1"
    declare -gA file
    file[path]=$(dirname -- "$arg")
    file[name]=$(basename -- "$arg")
    file[ext]=${arg##*.}
    readonly file
}

func1() {
    #local file="/path/to/a/file.log"

    func2 #"$file"
    func5 #"$file"
}

func2() {
    echo ${file[name]}
    echo ${file[ext]}

    #do stuff
}

func5() {
    echo ${file[path]}
}

setvars "/path/to/a/file.log"
func1

# error: file is immutable
file[ext]='abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting inheritance, which is pretty flexible.

```
$: f2(){ echo "${1:-${x:-empty}}"; }                        # arg precedent with default
$: f1(){ local x=foo; f2; x=bar f2; f2 baz; unset x; f2; }  # localize and try variations
$: x=test                                                   # set a global default
$: f2                                                       # use global default
test
$: x=different f2                                           # set an ephemeral default
different
$: f2 override                                              # pass an explicit value
override
$: x=different f2 override                                  # explicit argument wins
override
$: f1                                                       # test variations over local
foo
bar
baz
empty
$: echo $x                                                  # global default unchanged
test
```

In particular, note that when using `local` in `f1`, `unset x` only makes the local x unset; the `echo` at the end is still using the global definition of `x`.

So unless yours behaves differently, the `func1` value of `file` likely exists in it's called children, as would `name` and `ext` if it defined them, and the values were not overridden in the child functions. Obviously, those child functions *could* also override the inherited value if needed, in several ways.

Effectively, this lets you establish values for a heirarchical context.

## responding to question

- "Yes file is accessible to all child functions which is what I am not used to and it makes me wonder what is the point of ever passing variables in bash."

Your OP specifically asked how to share a group of variables with multiple functions in bash. Scoping can handle that, but is a very specific use case.

c.f. the [Basg Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions)'s comments:

> Functions serve a few purposes in a script... ***The second is to allow a block of code to be reused with slightly different arguments.***

A *func1* that depends on globals is entangled and state-dependent, which might be fine in the context of a single app - sometimes you just need a way to repeat a block of code. `x=foo func1` alters `$x` in that call, but requires knowledge of function internals. `func1 foo` does not.

If globals handle your needs with no side effects or namespace collisions, fine... but arguments make easier refactoring, *especially* if you store a useful function and source it in multiple scripts.

Some say if those things are a concern, use another language. It's a consideration...

## TL;DR

*func1 "$arg"* is generally preferred as safer, isolates from entanglements, doesn't pollute the namespace and risk collisions, doesn't require knowledge of function internals, and is arguably easier to maintain, refactor, and understand without scrolling around to read the function code.

Comment: Yes `file` is accessible to all child functions which is what I am not used to and it makes me wonder what is the point of ever passing variables in bash.